# terminate called without an active exception Aborted

Tags: c++, design-patterns, virtual-functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class Track{
public:
    Track(int t) : m_track(t){}
    int GetTrack() { return m_track; }
    void SetTrack(int track) { m_track = track; }
private:
    int m_track;
};

class Observer{
public:
    Observer(Track track) : m_track(track) { }
    virtual void run() = 0;
    virtual ~Observer(){
        cout << "Observer Destructor" << endl;
    }
protected:
    Track m_track;
    double running = 0;
};

class Rabbit : public Observer{
public:
    Rabbit(Track track) : Observer(track) { }
    void run(){
        while(running <= m_track.GetTrack()){
            running += 10;
            cout << "rabbit run " << running << endl;
            sleep(1);
            if(running == m_track.GetTrack() / 3 * 2){
                sleep(62);
            }
        }
        cout << "Rabbit win" << endl;
        //End another thread(Turtle thread);
    }
    ~Rabbit() = default;
};

class Turtle : public Observer{
public:
    Turtle(Track track) : Observer(track) { }
    void run(){
        while(running <= m_track.GetTrack()){
            running += 10.0 / 3;
            cout << "turtle run " << running << endl;
            sleep(1);
        }
        cout << "Turtle win" << endl;
        //End another thread(Rabbit thread);
    }
    ~Turtle() = default;
};

class Judge{
public:
    Judge(Track track) : m_track(track) { }
    void add(Observer* observer){
        observers.push_back(observer);  
    }

    void remove(Observer* observer){
        auto temp = find(observers.begin(), observers.end(), observer);
        if(temp != observers.end()){
            observers.erase(temp);
        }
    }

    void notify(){
        for(int i = 0; i != observers.size(); i++){
            //Start the thread to execute the run function of the subclass
            thread t([&](){
                observers[i]->run();
            });
            threads.push_back(&t);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i != observers.size(); i++){
            if(threads[i]->joinable())
                threads[i]->join();
        }
    }

    ~Judge() = default;

private:
    vector<Observer*> observers;
    Track m_track;
    vector<thread*> threads;
};

int main(){
    Track track(300);
    Observer* rabbit = new Rabbit(track);
    Observer* turtle = new Turtle(track);
    Judge* judge = new Judge(track);
    judge->add(rabbit);
    judge->add(turtle);
    judge->notify();
    delete rabbit;
    delete turtle;
    delete judge;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use the observer pattern, and call the *notify* function in the **Judge** class to notify the two subclasses to start the *run* function by thread, but i reported this error

```
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

How to fix this problem and add features in two subclass.
What this program solves is, suppose the track is 300 meters long, the speed of the tortoise is 10/3 m/s, the speed of the rabbit is 10 m/s, the tortoise keeps running, and the hare runs 2/3 of the way to the At 200 meters, after resting for 62 seconds, the tortoise won the race. try
(1) Write a program to simulate the process and results of the tortoise and the hare race according to the realization principle of the observer mode

Answer (score 2):

Two issues in one place:

```
for(int i = 0; i != observers.size(); i++){
            //Start the thread to execute the run function of the subclass
            thread t([&](){
                observers[i]->run();
            });
            threads.push_back(&t);
        }
```

The pointer you store in the vector becomes a dangling pointer right after you pushed it to the vector, because the `thread t` goes out of scope and gets destroyed. The destructor of `std::thread` terminates when you didn't `join` the thread.

Use a `std::vector<std::thread>` and make sure the threads are alive as long as you want to use them and dont get destroyed before you `join` them.

Perhaps you used pointers because `std::thread` cannot be copied, but it can be moved.

Comment: Thanks.I want to end another thread that has been called at the end of the run function in the already created thread, that is, the thread used to execute the run function of the turtle class at the end of the run function in the rabbit class, or vice versa. what should I do

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
threads.push_back(&t);
```

It pushes the pointer of a `std::thread` object to a vector, but the `std::thread` object goes out of scope directly after that. So, the `std::thread` object gets destroyed and leaves a dangling pointer in the `std::vector`.

Change the `vector` to hold the `std::thread` objects directly and use

```
threads.push_back(std::move(t));
```

to push the objects into the vector.

Also the `threads` variable does not have to be a member variable. It is enough to be a local variable in the `notify` function.

Full program: https://godbolt.org/z/bTWs9f69E

You can also use `emplace_back` to create the `thread` object in the `vector` directly and use ranged based `for` loops.

```
void notify(){
    vector<thread> threads;
    for(auto &observer : observers){
        //Start the thread to execute the run function of the subclass
        
        threads.emplace_back(thread([&observer](){
            observer->run();
        }));
    }
    for(auto &t : threads){
        if(t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: actually terminate is called before the pointer dangles, but its the same issue in OPs code

Comment: Thanks. I want to end another thread that has been called at the end of the run function in the already created thread, that is, the thread used to execute the run function of the turtle class at the end of the run function in the rabbit class, or vice versa. what should I do